# Conflict between pthread.h and gvc.h (graphviz)

Tags: c, pthreads, graphviz

I have searched using tag graphviz and "box" keyword, but have not found a solution to my problem.
I am running a simple code in C (using Xcode 5.1.1 and compiling with Apple LLVM 5.1) that uses both pthread.h (from libpthread.dylib) and gvc.h (from graphviz). But when I try to build it, it says :

geom.h

Semantic Issue – Redefinition of 'box' as different kind of symbol

I don't get this issue when using those two headers separately (I had a code using only graphviz, and tested some code using pthread only).
I checked where this geom.h was called: in types.h which is called in gvc.h.
I am rather newbie in C, so would like to know if any of you know about this issue.

Below is some basic code (I got an example for using pthread that I wanted to test for something else EDIT: just including both headers generates this issue... I'll remove the code) that generates this issue (I did add the header path for graphviz and library for pthread).
(I have not found another simple solution for multithreading that would not require installing many packages...)

Thank you very much in advance!

```
#include <gvc.h>
#include <pthread.h>
```